# How can I specify device in itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I have submitted an app in the app store only for iPhone 6 and above but there are all devices listed when I search on app store. From where I can set app compatibility.

[image]

Comment: Where have you specified it?

Comment: I haven't these devices anywhere in project or itunesconnect.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the iOS version given as minimum deployment target in the Xcode.
You have given the minimum supported version as iOS 8 and later. So it will be compatible with all devices that support iOS 8. So that was listed in the app store page.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify devices in App Store. It's availability depends upon the iOS version you provide support for. All the devices will be compatible which will have equal or greater OS version which you will define in your `Deployment Target`. You can restrict your app for `iPhone or iPad` . For this you need to change Device from your target setting.

You can see your settings in following screenshot.

[image: Settings for your app compatibility with device and OS version]